# Code to start at a certain time and stop at another

Tags: vba, excel, automation

I have a problem while trying to set up a macro on Excel to start at a certain time and stop at another. What I'm trying to achieve is:

A report gets generated every hour at XX with 12 minutes, this only happens from 8:12 to 11:12 everyday. Now my Excel file downloads the report from a source, pastes the values and updates the information, then it will auto publish it to Web format.

The problem is I have been using the following to try to achieve this but have been unsuccessful:

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:12:00"), "Macro Name", ("23:12:00")
```

Comment: What result are you getting vs. the expected result?

Comment: It will run it over and over again and I need to kill excel or else it will continue to consume resources

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the `OnTime` method recursively. Create a procedure like this `ScheduleNext` (the logic could be a bit more precise but you can work that out if needed...) and run it in the morning.  This will kick off your procedure at 8:12am.

```
Sub ScheduleNext()
    'Schedules the macro to run again in one hour
    If TimeValue(Now) < TimeValue("08:12:00 AM") Then
        Application.OnTime TimeValue("08:12:00 AM"), "MyMacro"
    ElseIf TimeValue(Now) < TimeValue("11:12:00 PM") Then
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("01:00:00"), "MyMacro"
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, in your procedure right before the `End Sub`, make a call to `ScheduleNext`.  This time, it will schedule the procedure to run again, in one hour.

```
Sub MyMacro()
''' your code ...
    Debug.Print "Time is " & TimeValue(Now)
    ScheduleNext  'Calls the schedule to run again in one hour
End Sub
```